# ANGULAR How to push to observable array? hero: Observable<Hero[]>

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, angularfire

Given an array:

```
// hero.service.ts
hero: Observable<Hero[]>;
```

How would you do something similar to: **hero.push(newHero)?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RxJS: How would I "manually" update an Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33324227/rxjs-how-would-i-manually-update-an-observable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but since you tagged firestore. I guess you could use angularfirestorecollection and map them to observable array later.

```
cardsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Card>;
  cardDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Card>;
  cards: Observable<Card[]>;
```

On init you will bind them together.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.cards = this.cardsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
    return changes.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Card;
      data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
      return data;
    });
  });
}
```

and then you can add cards to AngularFirestoreCollection.

```
addCard(card: Card) {
    this.cardsCollection.add(card);
}
```

Hope this helps. If you want to see my full code and project go to my [github](https://github.com/GreedyAlchemist/Destime/blob/master/src/app/services/cards.service.ts).

Comment: Great! Your example helped me understand some thing that made it work for me! Thanks! :)

Comment: I'm glad! you should edit the question fitting your solution.