# How to tell interval to wait for the last http call?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have http take say 10 seconds to complete (sometimes it take 1 second to complete) and interval run every 5 seconds.

I want interval to stop and wait until the http is complete then continue.

This is the reproduce the problem:

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-thunder-zycc2?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

```
  refresh$ = interval(5 * 1000).pipe(tap(() => this.load()));

  fakehttp() {
    return timer(10 * 1000).pipe(take(1));
  }

  load() {
    this.fakehttp().subscribe((r) => {
      console.log("data");
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.refresh$.subscribe((r) => {
      console.log("refresh!");
    });
  }
```

Comment: Is `timer`/`interval` an RxJS thing?

Comment: Yes. this is the reproduce the problem. I have http take say 10 seconds to complete (sometimes it take 1 second to complete) and interval run every 5 seconds. I want interval to stop and wait until the http is complete then continue.

Comment: OK, just wanted to make sure I read the correct documentation.

Comment: @VLAZ, yes. why not? `import { timer } from 'rxjs'`

Comment: I'm looking at the code in the question only.

Comment: I think interval is the wrong way. A response could trigger a new request with something like a debounce.

Comment: @jabaa I need to refresh the data every X seconds. what you suggest I do?

Comment: Subscribe to your backend request, add a timeout and send a new request.

Comment: I looking for rxjs operators can help me with that. the code is much cleaner with those operators. also if I use rxjs then I chain functions instead of callbacks. also why using setTimeout and not interval/timer? I get it free also in rxjs

Comment: _"why using setTimeout and not interval/timer?"_ Because with `setTimeout` you could solve the problem in 5 minutes. Probably you could use a timer for this but I don't know how

Comment: @jabaa it's not that much harder with RxJS. Same logic. Nicer outcome. I just need to read the docs because I've not used it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tap` to trigger the second observable results in multiple subscriptions.

#### Option 1

If I understand the question correctly, you're trying to re-trigger the HTTP request after 5 seconds AFTER the current request has emitted. In that case the time interval b/n the calls is dynamic. In that case you'd try to trigger the request manually after each notification using `BehaviorSubject`.

Try the following

```js
import { timer, BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class Sample implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  timerSrc = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);  // <-- default time
  close = new Subject<any>();  // <-- use to close open observables

  ngOnInit() {
    this.timerSrc.asObservable().pipe(
      takeUntil(this.close),
      switchMap((time: number) => timer(time)),
      switchMap(() => this.httpRequest())
    ).subscribe({
      next: (response: any) => {
        // use response
        this.timerSrc.next(5000);  // <-- call again in 5 seconds
      },
      error: (error: any) => {
        // handle error
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.close.next();  // <-- close open subscription 
  }
}
```

#### Option 2

If you do not mind have a fixed timer of 5 seconds b/n each successive calls, you could pipe to a timer with 5 second interval using `exhaustMap`. It'd ignore incoming emissions until the inner observable (the HTTP request) has emitted.

Note that here there would be no guarantee that each successive would have a fixed time interval of 5 seconds. It might be anything b/n 0 - 5 seconds depending on the time taken for the HTTP request to emit.

```js
import { timer, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { exhaustMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class Sample implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  close = new Subject<any>();  // <-- use to close open observables

  ngOnInit() {
    timer(0, 5000).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.close),
      exhaustMap(() => this.httpRequest())
    ).subscribe({
      next: (response: any) => {
        // use response
      },
      error: (error: any) => {
        // handle error
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.close.next();  // <-- close open subscription 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own observable that you manually update. Then set up a recursive `timeout()` call in `load()`. That way you always process the result and *then* wait 10 seconds. You you will not end up with premature update calls:

```
refresh$ = new Rx.Subject();

fakehttp() {
  return timer(10 * 1000).pipe(take(1));
}

load() {
  this.fakehttp().subscribe((r) => {
    console.log("data");

    //push value to observable
    refresh$.next(r);
    //schedule the next execution
    timer(10 * 1000)
      .subscribe(() => this.load());
  });
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.refresh$.subscribe((r) => {
    console.log("refresh!");
  });

  //start the update cycle
  this.load();
}
```

The manual observable update approach comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33356249/) of [luisgabrial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563187/luisgabriel);

Comment: I'm looking at the RxJS docs for a possibly better way to make and update observables.

Comment: the problem with this solution is you call `load` function recursive and not release the last call so it's open in the stack and may lead to a memory leak.
and what if I want just to load once? can I do it? I don't think so. you united the timer with the load functionality.

Comment: @ShlomiLevi AFAIK, `timer` runs and finishes. So, the `.subscribe` callback is cleared from the stack. Is that not the case for RxJS? "*what if I want just to load once?*" not the case with OP's code. OP explicitly wants periodic refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

A much better approach would use `interval` along with the `repeat` and `delay` operators, so that if the call is blocking, RXJS won't be stacking calls.

This exemple will try every 5 seconds. If the call it taking more that 5 seconds, it will wait.

```
this.logViewService.readLogs$().pipe(
        catchError((error: Error) => of({} as logViewDto)
        repeat({
            delay: () => interval(5000)
        }),
        takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef)
    ).subscribe((logViewDto: LogViewDto): void => {...})
```